# How to 'unravel' a dataframe using the values of the rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
class    passed       failed           extra_teaching
A11      1            2                0.5
A12      2            1                0.7
```

I want to 'unravel' the `DataFrame`, and lose the information about the class but keep the information on `extra_teaching`, so I end up with a row for each individual pupil who passed.

So the `DataFrame` should end up looking like this:

```
pass           extra_teaching
1              0.5
0              0.5 
0              0.5
1              0.7
1              0.7
0              0.7
```

I have no idea how to do this in `pandas`, except perhaps by using `iterrows()` and manually appending rows to a new `DataFrame` - has anyone got a neater way?

UPDATE:

I tried this, seems to work though not very elegant:

```
temp = []
df = df.set_index('class')
for idx in df.index:
    row = df.loc[idx]
    t = {'class': idx, 'extra_teaching': row['extra_teaching']}
    for i in range(0, int(row['passed'])):
        t['pass'] = 1
        temp.append(t)
    for i in range(0, int(row['failed'])):
        t['pass'] = 0
        temp.append(t)
df_exploded = pd.DataFrame(temp)
```

Comment: make class your index, loop over each element of it, compute the sum passed + failed for each row, and then create a dataframe for each row (e.g. each class) and concatenate all of them. You may want to introduce a column for each class in which you store the pass vector, e.g. [1 0 0] and [1 1 0] in this case. Should be simple from there

Comment: How do the three columns `class`,  `passed` and `failed` logically translate into `pass`?

Comment: @Stefan we ignore `class`, it's just there to explain what the data is. `passed` always translates to `pass=1`, `failed` always translates to `pass=0`.

Comment: @tschm so `df.set_index('class')` then `for idx in df.index:...something?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def teaching_results(x):
    num_rows = x.passed.iloc[0] + x.failed.iloc[0]
    passed = x.passed.iloc[0] * [1] + x.failed.iloc[0] * [0]
    extra_teaching = num_rows * [x.extra_teaching.iloc[0]]
    class_code = x['class'].iloc[0]
    return pd.DataFrame({'pass': passed, 'extra_teaching': extra_teaching, 'class': class_code})

df.groupby('class', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: teaching_results(x))
```

to get:

```
    class  extra_teaching  pass
0 0   A11             0.5     1
  1   A11             0.5     0
  2   A11             0.5     0
1 0   A12             0.7     1
  1   A12             0.7     1
  2   A12             0.7     0
```

Comment: Ah great. Thanks so much. Is there any way to retain the `class` variable as a column in the above, rather than it changing to `0`, `1` etc?